# Referencing nested TypeScript modules

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, module, typescript

I have the following situation:

```
/*file A/Z.ts*/
///<reference path="B/Y.ts"/>
module A{
    import Y = B.Y;
    export class Z{
        //use class Y
    }
}


/*file A/B/Y.ts*/
///<reference path="../Z.ts"/>
module A.B{
    import Z = A.Z;
    export class Y{
        //use class Z
    }
}
```

Which seems to compile fine however I get javascript issues.
When calling `var y = new Y()` in the chrome dev console I get: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and looking in the generated JavaScript the IntelliJ code inspection notes that `B` is private and not accessible.

It's worth noting that all my .ts are compiled into a single file.

EDIT: On further inspection it is an ordering issue. Moving the declarations around in the generated javascript fixed the JavaScript errors.
The issue only came about when I started wrapping my classes in modules. i.e. the ordering was fine pre-modules making me assume all my ref's are fine.

TSC Version is 1.5.0-beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assumed it was an ordering issue. I fixed the issue by re-examining my `///<reference path=""/>` statements and removing the `///<reference path="../Z.ts"/>` from `Y.ts`.

After reading through [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1359)
It seems that it is not needed because the compiler would have already loaded `Z.ts` by this stage and including it just changed the ordering.